# For how long does the google bot wait after document ready before taking a snapshot of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

As the google bot lets the JS do its work on the page while crawling, for how long does it wait to let the javascript execute after document ready ?

Suppose I have an AJAX response that takes longer than usual, how to make sure that the google bot crawls the content rich site (with the AJAX response) ?

I tried to do some experiment with that and found out that it waits for around 5 seconds. Is it a standard result for everyone ? Has google provided any documentation around this ?

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot has timeouts, but they're generally longer than 5 seconds. If a query takes too long, the bot will often leave it and retry later. Over time if it consistently times out, or takes too long, Google will assume this is also a bad user experience and either ignore the content or rank it very poorly.

Remember, page speed is becoming an increasingly important ranking factor.

Comment: On what evidence or documentation is this answer based?